# SQLAlchemy recovery after a rollback "This transaction is inactive"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to recover after a primary key violation in an insert, by logging the duplicate user to another table. However, my code produces the error `InvalidRequestError: This transaction is inactive`.

Unfortunately the traceback doesn't show the specific line within this function where the error occurs--it only goes as deep as the function calling this function (which is strange).

Does my try/except begin/rollback/commit pattern look correct?

```
def convert_email(db, user_id, response):
    """Map a submitted email address to a user, if the user
    does not yet have an email address.
    """
    email = response['text_response']
    trans = db.begin()
    try:
        update_stmt = users_tbl.update(
                and_(users_tbl.c.user_id==user_id,
                     users_tbl.c.email==None))
        db.execute(update_stmt.values(dict(email=email)))
        trans.commit()
    except sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError as e:
        trans.rollback()
        if e.orig.pgcode == UNIQUE_VIOLATION:
            trans = db.begin()
            try:
                user = db.execute(users_tbl.select(users_tbl.c.email==email))
                parent_user_id = user.first()['user_id']

                insert_stmt = duplicate_public_users_tbl.insert().values(
                        user_id=user_id,
                        parent_id=parent_user_id)
                db.execute(insert_stmt)
                trans.commit()
            except sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError as e:
                trans.rollback()
                if e.orig.pgcode != UNIQUE_VIOLATION:
                    raise
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception was being produced by the calling function, which itself was wrapped in a transaction.

```
with engine.begin() as db:
    convert_email(db, user_id, response)
```

The inner `rollback()` call must terminate the outer transaction as well. This is hinted at by the documentation for `Transaction.close()`,

> ... This is used to cancel a Transaction without affecting the scope of an enclosing transaction.